# Cannot Export a Table from BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export a table from big query to google cloud storage from console/command line. The console job runs for a few minutes and errors out without any error code and the command line job also after running for sometime gives the below error:

BigQuery error in extract operation: Error processing job 'data-flow-experiment:bqjob_r308ff0f73d1820a6_00000157f77e8ab9_1': Backend error. Job aborted.

Job id of the command line is given above.

The billing is enabled for the project and the big query service is also enabled.

Also I get the below error when I try to create a bucket in the Google Cloud Storage:
AccessDeniedException: 403 The account for the specified project is read only.

Though the IAM user I am using has owner access and I have created buckets using this account previously and have also extracted tables in the past.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

For the bigquery issue:
Do you happen to have a timestamp column which have out-of-range values (say, far far far into the future)?
If so, you can just wait for two more days, as the fix is

Comment: The fix I mentioned should be released. Please let me know if you still see the same issue from bigquery.

Comment: No there is no date that is in future. It was some billing related issue. Thanks for the help.